# JSON Schema puts null values when validation fails on nested objects instead of throwing error

Tags: json, jsonschema, fastify

I am using fastify with `fluent-json-schema` to validate the server requests/responses and I am having trouble regarding nested validations with `oneOf`. Here's my simple schema using fastify fluent:

```
const textTypeSchema = S.object()
    .prop('id', S.integer())
    .prop('type', S.const('TEXT'))
    .prop('text', S.string().required());

const dateTypeSchema = S.object()
    .prop('id', S.integer().required())
    .prop('type', S.const('DATE'))
    .prop('date', S.string().required());

const schema = {
    response: {
        200: S.object()
            .prop('someValue', S.integer().required())
            .prop(
                'someObjectWithType',
                S.required().oneOf([textTypeSchema, dateTypeSchema])
            )
    }
};
```

Which in turn is transformed to this:

```
{
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "someValue":{
         "type":"integer"
      },
      "someObjectWithType":{
         "oneOf":[
            {
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                  "id":{
                     "type":"integer"
                  },
                  "type":{
                     "const":"TEXT"
                  },
                  "text":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               },
               "required":[
                  "text"
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                  "id":{
                     "type":"integer"
                  },
                  "type":{
                     "const":"DATE"
                  },
                  "date":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               },
               "required":[
                  "id",
                  "date"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "someValue",
      "someObjectWithType"
   ]
}
```

Now comes the problem, and I am not sure where it lies. When I use [this](https://jsonschema.dev/s/uJ0a1) online schema validator the validation fails as expected when the response doesn't match one of the schemas provided in the `oneOf` array but the fastify server, instead of throwing an error when the validation fails like it would if a top level property was missing, just sets the property that failed validation to `null`, in this case `someObjectWithType`.

On top of that I tried to add `.not(S.null())` to the schema in order to ensure that it throws the error if ends up null but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing here and how can I make the validation throw an error in this case?

Comment: Can you share the instance (data) that's causing the unexpected behavior?

Comment: @gregsdennis I am not exactly sure what you mean by instance. To add a bit more information, I am using fastify 3.25.1 and json schema draft 7

Comment: "instance" is the data being validated

Comment: I left a link in the question but here it is https://jsonschema.dev/s/uJ0a1

Answer (score 0):

The JSON schema you set on the `response` is used to *serialize* the response's payload.
It is not used **to validate** your response's payload.

Under the hood [`fast-json-stringify`](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify/) is used, you can check how it is working.
In general, it filters out properties that are not listed in the JSON schema and coerce or hide properties that do not match the `type` configuration.

If you want an error to be thrown by your endpoint if your response is not valid you need to use this plugin [`fastify-response-validation`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-response-validation).

Note that this has a performance cost, as you are checking what your application is returning to the client.

---

Side note: I think that the response payload should not be **validated** because it returns data from your system and it is server-side content.
So validating the input before inserting it into the application, grants that the output will be compliant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense. I wonder, though, why it fails (with an error) if the missing prop is on the top level. Any idea?

Comment: `if a top level property was missing` -> because it tries to access an undefined field likely: do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: The error when a top level property is missing is explicitly saying: 'Field "something" is required!'

Comment: Here's a complete stacktrace if that helps: 
 ```"stack": Error: "id" is required!
      at $main (eval at build (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fast-json-stringify/index.js:155:20), <anonymous>:189:15)
      at serialize (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js:733:12)
      at preserializeHookEnd (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js:373:15)
      at preserializeHook (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js:358:5)
      at _Reply.Reply.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js:190:7)
      at /usr/src/app/node_modules/fastify/lib/wrapThenable.js:23:15```

Comment: Reading the docs `If the object to stringify is missing the required field(s), fast-json-stringify will throw an error.`

Comment: Yes, but only happens if the missing property is in the top level.